# Click a checkbox to auto-select a corresponding option

Tags: javascript, html, select, checkbox

I have the following form with various checkbox inputs and a select box with various options.

When the user clicks on a checkbox I want the corresponding option is auto selected.

*Examples:*

When the user clicks on the 'input' with value="Boat Available" then the 'option' with `value="1"` is selected.

When the user clicks on the 'input' with value="Spaces Available" then the 'option' with value="3" is selected.

Here is the form:

```html
<form>
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title1" value="Boat Available">Boat Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title2" value="Spaces Available">Spaces Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title3" value="Fully Booked">Fully Booked
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title4" value="Not Available">Not Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title5" value="Short Trip">Short Trip
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title6" value="Trip Cancelled">Trip Cancelled
</form>


<select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category">
  <option id="101" value="1">Boat Available</option>
  <option id="103" value="3">Spaces Available</option>
  <option id="104" value="4">Fully Booked</option>
  <option id="105" value="5">Not Available</option>
  <option id="10204" value="204">Short Trips</option>
  <option id="10180" value="180">Trip Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What if there's more than one checkbox?

Comment: 1. You want a radio 2. options do not have IDs 3. set the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you are interested in selecting one option at a time (it didn't make any sense otherwise). Changed all checkboxes into radio buttons because you need to pick only one category at a time. Also the `<form>` is wrapped around everything.

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the <form>
var form = document.forms.main;
/*
Register the change event to form 
When <form> is changed call sync()
*/
form.onchange = sync;

// sync() passes Event Object
function sync(event) {
  // Reference all form tags under <form>
  var ui = this.elements;
  // Reference the changed radio button
  var tgt = event.target;
  // Find the radio button id and extract the number -1
  var idx = (tgt.id.split('').pop()) - 1;
  // Reference the <select>
  var cat = ui.category;
  // Reference the <option> at the position of idx
  var opt = cat.options[idx];
  // Select that <option>
  opt.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title1" value="Boat Available">Boat Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title2" value="Spaces Available">Spaces Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title3" value="Fully Booked">Fully Booked
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title4" value="Not Available">Not Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title5" value="Short Trip">Short Trip
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title6" value="Trip Cancelled">Trip Cancelled<br>

  <select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category">
    <option id="101" value="1">Boat Available</option>
    <option id="103" value="3">Spaces Available</option>
    <option id="104" value="4">Fully Booked</option>
    <option id="105" value="5">Not Available</option>
    <option id="10204" value="204">Short Trips</option>
    <option id="10180" value="180">Trip Cancelled</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: At the moment it is not working for me, I will check my code against yours very carefully and report back..

Comment: @Weyboat I wrapped the `<form>` tag around everything, that's probably why. Is there any particular reason why the `<select>` isn't in the same `<form>` as the checkboxes/radios are in?

Comment: Yes the select box is used in an array of select elements. I just tried moving the closing </form> tag to below the select box but since it is part of an array, it gets positioned below multiple select boxes..

Comment: Does FF work using the demo on this site? It works for me.

Comment: Yes I have a new file with working code, I just need to translate into my existing code.. I may be a while but thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes to the HTML (actually only to make it valid) you can do this:

**Initialise based on dropdown**

```js
document.getElementById("main")
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    if (e.target.name == "title") document.getElementById("category").value = e.target.value;
  });
// Initialise based on dropdown
document.querySelector("[name=title][value='"+document.getElementById("category").value+"']").click();
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title1" value="1">Boat Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title2" value="3">Spaces Available
  <input name="title" checked type="radio" class="formElements" id="title3" value="4">Fully Booked
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title4" value="5">Not Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title5" value="204">Short Trip
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title6" value="180">Trip Cancelled<br>

  <select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category">
    <option value="1">Boat Available</option>
    <option value="3">Spaces Available</option>
    <option value="4">Fully Booked</option>
    <option value="5">Not Available</option>
    <option value="204">Short Trips</option>
    <option value="180">Trip Cancelled</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

**Initialise based on radio**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#main [name=title]").forEach(function(chk) {
  chk.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("category").value = this.value;
  })
});

// initialise based on radio

document.querySelector("[name=title]:checked").click();
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title1" value="1">Boat Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title2" value="3">Spaces Available
  <input name="title" checked type="radio" class="formElements" id="title3" value="4">Fully Booked
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title4" value="5">Not Available
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title5" value="204">Short Trip
  <input name="title" type="radio" class="formElements" id="title6" value="180">Trip Cancelled<br>

  <select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category">
    <option value="1">Boat Available</option>
    <option value="3">Spaces Available</option>
    <option value="4">Fully Booked</option>
    <option value="5">Not Available</option>
    <option value="204">Short Trips</option>
    <option value="180">Trip Cancelled</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using checkboxes (multiple of which can be checked in parallel), what you want needs a `select` that allows for multiple picks, so I added the attribute `multiple`:

```js
let options = Array.from(category.querySelectorAll('option'));

document.forms[0].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  options.find(o=>o.textContent===e.target.value).selected = e.target.checked;
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title1" value="Boat Available">Boat Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title2" value="Spaces Available">Spaces Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title3" value="Fully Booked">Fully Booked
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title4" value="Not Available">Not Available
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title5" value="Short Trip">Short Trip
  <input name="title" type="checkbox" class="formElements" id="title6" value="Trip Cancelled">Trip Cancelled
</form>

<select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category" multiple>
  <option id="101" value="1">Boat Available</option>
  <option id="103" value="3">Spaces Available</option>
  <option id="104" value="4">Fully Booked</option>
  <option id="105" value="5">Not Available</option>
  <option id="10204" value="204">Short Trip</option>
  <option id="10180" value="180">Trip Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The user should only be able to select one checkbox and not multiple, can this be amended to work that way?

Comment: Changing the checkbox to a radio and removing the 'multiple' got your code working thank you..

Comment: @Weyboat Honestly, that was **your** fault, not mine. My answer was correct in the first place, your specifications were unclear regarding this and your approach was misleading. Spend more effort on your next question, please.

Comment: your correct of course, it was my fault and your code helped me discover my error. Thank You..